# Calling a controller method from CUserIdentity

Tags: php, facebook, yii, facebook-login

I'm implementing Facebook Login with HybridAuth. I'm getting the FB profile just fine, but I'm a little bit confused as to what to do with it. I'm comparing with my registered users table to check if I already have the user e-mail from the FB profile, if I have, then the login completes with the stored account, if not, I create a new user account and store it in my DB.
The thing is, when I create a new user I call a method in my user controller, like this:

```
UserController::createUserSocialNetwork($userprofile);
```

Yii does not let me do this as the class for the controller file has not been imported yet. I understand that I can import the controller class in my Yii config file or I can use `Yii::app()->runController` from a class that extends `CUserIdentity`, personally I'm leaning towards the former, but I'm not quite sure if any of them is the right approach. So my question is: how should I do this without compromising Yii core features? Is importing a controller file in the config breaking any of the design rules that Yii follows?

Comment: Can you move the logic from `UserController::createUserSocialNetwork` into the `User` model, and call `UserModel::createUserSocialNetwork` from both `UserController::createUserSocialNetwork` and from your login script?

Comment: Why are you handling user creation in user identity at the first place? shouldn't you handle it inside controller action?

Comment: i would change the design of my application and move this logic to the user model (not a best practice of course) or create helper class

Comment: @Stu I not sure if it is a good practice to make Create operations outside of the controller class, but it might be an easier approach.

Comment: @osmancode I realize that creating an user in CUserIdentity is weird, partially because I not quite sure if CUserIdentity could be considered as an user in the first place. Your suggestion to move to the model class seems good, but then again, won't that mean I am removing control out of the controller class?

Comment: @osmancode I decided to go with the helper class, I don't think it is the best solution but it makes more sense than what I have or putting in the model class. Thanks, if you want you can write an answer and I will assign it as the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I strongly suggest handling the user creation in Controller Action instead of UserIdentity.
if this is not possible you can move the logic to controller behavior or helper class or even to the User Model ( and all of these alternative options are not a best design practice ).